# I want to position the contents of below HTML and CSS same as per the attached reference image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position my contents of below `HTML` and `CSS` same as per the reference image and I am using flex-box as there are going to be seven rows but I am unable to get the layout position as in the image as the `price-para` of `USD/DAY and Total 76.93 USD` are not getting positioned under `price-header` and `SELECT`. Please if anyone can make me understand how to rectify it.

[image: Example]

HTML

```
<div class="body-div">
        <div class="car-container">
          <div class="car-rows">
            <div class="price-div">
              <h1 class="price-header">10.99</h1>
              <p class="price-para">USD/DAY</p>
              <button>SELECT</button>
              <p class="price-para">Total 76.93 USD</p>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.body-div {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.2vmin;
  }

  .car-container {
    flex: 1;
    width: 75%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .car-rows {
    display: flex;
  }

  .price-div {
    width: 16%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an image in your question. Please also make your code into a runnable snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing that.

Answer (score 0):

share your reference image,
make your two price-para class into one and add below button tag.